# How to implement an always-on-top widget that hides when losing focus

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I need to implement a top-level widget (fixed position on screen) that hides whenever the user clicks somewhere else in the desktop, but it should hide gradually, so the widget should still be visible when it happens. To simplify, I want something like the Windows 8 right sidebar, when the user pushes a button, like the Super key it comes up, when clicking somewhere else it fades away, but is still visible in the process.

This is, I want to have an always-on-top window that hides when it loses focus. I have implemented this in pyqt4 but it is not working.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Signals(QtCore.QObject):

    close = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

class Menu(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, signals):
        super(Menu, self).__init__()
        self.signals = signals

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        # Just simplificating the gradual hiding effect for the moment
        self.signals.close.emit() 

    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        print "FocusOut"
        self.signals.close.emit()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    signals = Signals()
    signals.close.connect(app.quit)

    w = Menu(signals)
    w.setWindowFlags( QtCore.Qt.SplashScreen )
    w.resize(200, 200)
    w.move(0, 0)
    w.setWindowTitle('Test')
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, this is not working. When I click somewhere else the widget won't enter the focusOutEvent. I've also tried installing an eventFilter but since the window is a SplashScreen it won't work.

Any ideas on how to tackle this?